# Doesn't java have pointer?

Tags: java, pointers

Hi everyone who read this post, i have a question about java programming. Is that java have pointer? I heard someone said "Java has pointer" and other person said "Java doesn't have pointer" ? I need a explain about this question.

Comment: "I heard someone" Who, where? "and other person said" who, where?

Comment: Java *does* have pointers, but they are called _references_ (the clue is in the name `Null**Pointer**Exception`, which is thrown when you invoke a method on a null _reference_). They differ from C++ pointers insofar as you can't do arithmetic on them.

Comment: ... and that a pure Java program cannot get into a situation where a reference points to some random place in memory.